# Save data in SQLite with Category

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have to save data in specific category. And I am putting these category names as SQLite Column.

And SQLite column are looking like below. Where the COL2 is the category.

```
COL1                 COL2                COL3

13-11-2018           Monitor             4
13-11-2018           Monitor             2
13-11-2018           Mouse               6
14-11-2018           Keyboard            5
14-11-2018           Monitor             3
```

Now What I want is to show unique category name to a list view. Like:

```
Monitor
Mouse
Keyboard
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: You have problem in query or in listview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use distinct keyword before column name while select data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL2 FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to filter duplicate entry using a query if you want to show `COL2` in `listView` or `Recyclerview`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 COL2
FROM
 table;
```

for more help visit [this link](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-select-distinct)